# SQL Regex to Java Regex

Tags: java, sql, regex, string, replaceall

I have a regular expression that can be used in SQL to Reduce the size of my webpage URL Data.

I am trying to use the Same Regex in java Code to perform similar operation on webpage URL

This Regex is not working in JAVA, I am thinking it has some thing to do with Escape characters.

This is my SQL REGEX

```
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(page_nm, 'http(s:|:)|^.+?:| - PY abcdabcd Careers|^\w+(\/\/|\/)|(\/\/)|PLoad\?pagename=|(\[.].+|)(\/(grid|amtdGP|cgi-bin|wsi|Dotnet)((\/wwws|\/apps\/u\/)(\/research|)|))|\[?].+', ''),'\[?]pagename=|(\/data\/company\/tdat\/)|:','/') as EVENT_WBPG_NM
```

I am trying to do some thing like below in my java code.

```
jsonObj.getSystemDetails().getUrl().replaceall("http(s:|:)|^.+?:| - PY abcdabcd Careers|^\w+(\/\/|\/)|(\/\/)|PLoad\?pagename=|(\[.].+|)(\/(grid|amtdGP|cgi-bin|wsi|Dotnet)((\/wwws|\/apps\/u\/)(\/research|)|))|\[?].+","").replaceall("\[?]pagename=|(\/data\/company\/tdat\/)|:","/");
```

How to make this Regex Compile in JAVA and what are the changes that need to be done?

Comment: Replace all `\/` with `/` and then ``\`` with ``\\`` However, `\[?]` looks suspicious - should it match `[?]` or just `?`? Same question is about `\[.]` - is it a dot or a `[.]`?

Comment: Is `getUrl()..replaceall` with the 2 `.` a copy/paste error or is it like this in your code ?

Comment: You are right copy paste error.

Comment: Ok, let me suggest straight: try `.replaceAll("http(s:|:)|^.+?:| - PY abcdabcd Careers|^\\w+//?|//|PLoad\\?pagename=|([.].+|)(/(grid|amtdGP|cgi-bin|wsi|Dotnet)((/wwws|/apps/u/)(/research|)|))|[?].+","").replaceAll("[?]pagename=|(/data/company/tdat/)|:","/");` - though without an example string, it seems just not feasible.